# Node js server can only listen but does not establish connection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

Been trying to create a simple node.js server that send emails to specified email address with the help of sendgrid's API. The code was running just fine earlier. However, after I tried to deploy the server using Heroku, terminal indicates the server is listening but does not respond to browser requests.(The browser is just taking forever to load the page and will eventually fail to connect.) I don't recall making any changes to the code. Here is the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) that I followed.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("accessories"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
})

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    let emailTo = req.body.email;
    let subjectLine = req.body.subject;
    let message = req.body.body;

    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    const msg = {
        to: emailTo,
        from: 'example@example.com',
        subject: subjectLine,
        text: message, 
        // html: message,
    }

    sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
        res.sendFile('success.html', {root: '.'});
        console.log('Email sent');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.sendFile('failure.html' + error, {root: '.'});
        console.error(error);
  })

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(msg);
  console.log(jsonData);
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is listenning on port 3000.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you included above is exactly what's being deployed, it is likely because the PORT is hard-coded to 3000 in `app.listen`

I haven't touched Heroku in a while, but I remember their Dyno's expose a PORT environmental variable (`process.env.PORT`)-- use that to set your port, ex:

```
const portNumber = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(portNumber, function(){
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${portNumber}`);
});
```

Try a redeploy and see if that helps your issue-- see here for Heroku's "official" starter repo which should deploy properly and you can modify as you need: https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made the change and somehow it still shows me the same error. However, I was eventually able to solve the issue by:

1. change the port number according to your suggestion;
2. clear the npm cache;
3. kill all nodes;
4. remove the 'node module' folder & package.json file and reinstall them.